# How are exponents simplified/refactored when they belong under a cube-root radical?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I'm reading a [cryptography paper](http://marc.info/?l=cryptography&m=115694833312008) and am trying to understand the math behind it. In the paper, one expression is given and refactored into another, equivalent expression. I'm having trouble understanding how the conversion was done.

This expression:
$\sqrt[3]{2^{3057} - N*2^{2072} + G}$

is supposed to be equivalent this one:
$2^{1019} - (N * 2^{34}/3)$

I understand how the second expression was calculated, except for where $2^{34}$ came from. It looks like everything's being divided by 3, but since the exponent $2072$ doesn't divide perfectly by 3, something was done to it. Can anyone explain?

Comment: amWhy, you posted a comment with an answer, did you delete it? You said to factor out $2^{2038}$ and I was going to ask how you arrived at that value.

Comment: Is G a constant? How it is calculated and evaluated?
Maybe the answer is behind of G.